# Restoring previous file versions through Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, synchronization, online-storage, version-control

I have an InDesign file that I've been working on that is stored in my Google Drive folder. I am trying to restore it to a previous version.

However I see no option for it based on what I read online... all I see is the following:

[image]

Do I really have to download it manually and then move it into my Drive folder, only to end up syncing it again?

Answer (score 1):

While it's [easy to do for Google files](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190843), [Google Drive's support documentation](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2409045?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) says in reference to non-Google files that

> Only the most recent versions of past documents will be saved, unless you click Keep forever.

So you probably won't be able to get the old version for that file.

---

The closest you can get for this type of file is looking at the `i` ("View details") in the top right. It will show you uploads, deletions, etc. and you may be able to find something useful to you there.

Comment: I managed to get the old file just fine... is Google saying that it will only keep the current version of the file? The one I restored was several versions old, from the day before

Comment: According to the wording in the quote above, it could keep a couple recent copies, not just the *most* recent, but it's not explicitly clear

Comment: Google's information does seem strangely open to interpretation! I suppose it must be saying that it won't store *every* version of a file