# How to revert docx file to its original state after it was opened in gdocs?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, office-365

At work, we use Google Drive as the repository for most files. Some of these files are Microsoft Office files : .docx (Word), .xslx (Excel), .pptx (Powerpoint).

Let's take the case of a .docx file. If a user browses Google Drive in the web interface, they can open the .docx file directly. This causes Google Doc to directly import the .docx file into Google Docs. However, **this causes permanent modifications to the original .docx file**.

[image]

Sometimes this is useful and convenient, because it allows Office users and Gdocs users to easily and collaboratively work on the same file (though not really in real time).

Sometimes this is very painful and permanently breaks all formatting in the .docx file, because some specific Word features cannot be easily imported into Google Docs (formatting using themes, specific fonts, etc.).
In any case, I don't think simply *opening* a file should ever bring seemingly irreversible changes to the file.

Is there a way to revert the changes that bring the file to what it was just before it was opened from the Google Drive interface?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. First, opening a docx using Google Drive editor  doesn't convert the file to Google Docs automatically, but it's true that editing the file might affect some features. Fortunately Google Drive has a version history... we already have some questions about the Google Drive version history like https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/107108/88163.

Comment: Not really an answer, but you can turn autoconversion off in Drive settings.

Comment: @IanHyzy thanks a lot — the option is already turned off (the file is, as Ruben mentioned, not technically converted into a gdoc file, but opening it within gdrive still brings some desctructive layout changes to it, which I haven't found how to revert...)

Comment: Do you see a blue DOCX label next to the title when opening the file?